# Angular scope not updating live on screen after function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been making a function that will 'like' a photo.

Every on the API side works but I cannot get the current picture in the ng repeat to update its data.

Heres the basic html:

```
<div ng-repeat="update in updates" class="custom-card">
  <div class="heading">
    <span class="title">
      {{update.data.project.name}}
      {{update.data.user.name}}
    </span>
  </div>
  <img on-double-tap="likeUpdate({{update}})" class="full-image" ng-src="imagelink.com/{{update.image.name}}" imageonload>
</div>
```

Then in that function I am doing this for testing:

```
$scope.likeUpdate = function(update) {
    update.data.user.name = 'test';
    console.log('function ran');
};
```

But nothing is changing on the current page. The console.log is showing the function has been called and if I console.log

```
console.log(update.data.user.name)
```

It correctly shows 'test'.

Any help?

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Comment: update is simple varible not $scope variable so you cannot get reflected in html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
on-double-tap="likeUpdate({{update}})"
```

should be

```
on-double-tap="likeUpdate(update)"
```

because you need to pass in the actual variable, not its value.

Comment: Jeez, how obvious. Thanks! Solved my headache for a couple of days!

Comment: @Lovelock hah, I've had those headaches too. glad it helped